# Map an ID array to a string array using via an object list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

```
var myIds = [3, 4, 2];

var myObj = [
    {id:1, name:'one'}, 
    {id:2, name:'two'},
    {id:3, name:'tree'},
    {id:4, name:'four'}];

// need to obtain ['tree', 'four', 'two']

var idsToNames= function(ids, objects) {
    var myNames = myIds.map(function(id){
        // transform id to name
        foreach(o in objects){
            if (i.id == id) 
                return o.name;
        }
    });
    return myNames;
}
```

Is it the optimal way to transform a *id* array into a *name* array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First transform your object like this

```
var newMyObj = myObj.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
  result[currentObject.id] = currentObject.name;
  return result;
}, {});

console.log(newMyObj);
// { '1': 'one', '2': 'two', '3': 'three', '4': 'four' }
```

---

You can actually create the `newMyObj` by iterating the array `myObj`, like this as well

```
var newMyObj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i += 1) {
  newMyObj[myObj[i].id] = myObj[i].name;
}
```

---

Now, you can simply iterate `myIds` and pick values from `newMyObj`, like this

```
console.log(myIds.map(function(id) { return newMyObj[id]; }));
// [ 'three', 'four', 'two' ]
```

If your environment supports ECMAScript 2015's Arrow functions, this can be written succinctly as

```
console.log(myIds.map((id) => newMyObj[id]));
// [ 'three', 'four', 'two' ]
```

By transforming your original `myObj` to `newMyObj` you will be getting constant time lookup. Otherwise you have to iterate the `myObj` array for every element in the `myIds` and runtime complexity will become O(n*m).